# Pass additional parameter to paypal button url

Tags: paypal

I created a paypal button to manage my subscriptions and I´m planning to use it with my own link. Im not using the javascript SDK

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=0000&custom=123">Pay now</a>
```

I was able to find that you can pass the &custom=123 parameter
but when I fetch a single subscription with

```
https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/123
```

I don´t see the value of custom but I do see it in the POST request to my IPN endpoint. that means Paypal is sending it.

how can I see this custom value in the subscription itself? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Either: change to using a JavaScript SDK subscribe button and provide your value in the `createSubscription`'s `custom_id` field

Or: continue using the legacy Subscribe button/link and try querying a v1/payments sale or v2/payments capture using a completed transaction ID for the subscription (not a profile ID), which might map to containing that legacy Subscribe transaction's `custom` value

Comment: isn´t the javascript SDK an easier way to just compose the paypal url? can I emulate that somehow?

Comment: No, that is not what it is.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<button onclick="pay()">Pay now</button>
<script>
function pay() {
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr",
  type: "get",
  data: { 
    cmd: _s-xclick, 
    hosted_button_id: 0000, 
    custom: 123
  },
  success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});
}
</script>
```